# Using prolog without the pl file

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog

My python application works well and uses swi_prolog's consult, asserts, and query functions along with a pl file. However, when I call the code via web (I get access error at consult when trying to open the pl file).

So, I thought of using the prolog without the pl file consultation. I just want to embed the pl file content into prolog in a way so that I can use it in a similar way and I can continue with the query steps. Is there anyone who can guide me in doing this?

Thanks in advance,
Ferda

Comment: Is this the same [problem](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/getting-access-violation-error-when-using-prolog-as-a-part-of-a-web-app/4697?u=ericgt) cross posted on the SWI-Prolog Discourse forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SWI-Prolog manual has a chapter on [deploying applications](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=runtime). In particular, it allows you to create so-called [saved states](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=saved-states) of your program. This mechanism allows you to create a stand-alone package from your application, either from inside the application or [from the command line](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=cmdlinecomp).